Nested dependencies or library are not available in generated AAR , Unable to import the class or library used in module to root project
Hi I'm new to android developed, So please excuse any basic mistakes
Developing a KMM project and need to include this as an external dependencies in another project
So converted this KMM project a library (AAR)
After adding this as an dependencies to another native compose project the compose function of android KMM is available to call from root(parent) project and the UI also rendering but the problem is the module of KMM shared class are not available to import.
just to cross-check I have added the aar of the shared module into the root project then it's available to import .
My question is since the KMM android project has the included the shared module of KMM in it's dependencies build.gradle and in settings.gradle.kts why does the aar of KMM android does not include the nested dependencies or it's own external dependencies like koin, coil , ktor
Error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "coil.compose.SingletonAsyncImageKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Xr86WRb8oZvcDEMKe2nugA==/com.kobil.integratelibrary-NZ1-2io6hAVQ8eDJK4wSXg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Xr86WRb8oZvcDEMKe2nugA==/com.kobil.integratelibrary-NZ1-2io6hAVQ8eDJK4wSXg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
Root(parent) project which has AAR under libs inside app module , And using the compose funs of module in mainActivity

KMM project made changes done from application to library and it's working fine, the UI is rendering in root project which is declared in KMM android activity.

Ran this on terminal to generate AAR
./gradlew assembleRelease

When use 3rd library, ex.: ktor, ... in KMM project. You must include that dependency in native project also to able implement it.
Other thing, if KMM project include nested module, after build *.aar. Native project MUST include all *.aar from /module & root prj.

No need I was able use nested dependencies from the aar itself without including it manually, kindly check the accepted ans

I'm answering my own question and uploaded a sample solution in repo
https://github.com/Prathiv07/KMMasModule
Issue with Uploading a Library to Maven: Nested Module Not Available in Final AAR
I've been facing an issue while uploading a library to Maven. The structure of my project is as follows:
Library
app module: Originally an application, I converted it to a library that needs to be used in another project. this module use the shared module
shared module: Contains business logic and default libraries.
When I generate an AAR for the app module and use it in another project, the shared module is not found, leading to issues. I tried various solutions, including adding POM dependencies, but none worked.
Finally, I resolved the issue by uploading both the app module AAR and the shared module AAR to Maven. After doing this, the final AAR library worked fine.
